# Не коммитятся файлы в git появляются угловые кавычки

Tags: git

при попытки закомитить файлы в терминале вылезают ненужные кавычки, приглашающие вводить дальше, а файлы просто напросто не коммитятся
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
работаю в visual sudio code

Comment: Тот случай, когда лучше показать хоть скриншон

Comment: Точно не уверен, но может пробел после `-m` поставьте?

Comment: так я же приложил

Comment: @РусланКамов вы приложили скриншот из ВКонтакте, а он как минимум заблокирован в некоторых странах

Comment: andreymal сработало, спасибо, очень странно меня учили что пробел нельзя там ставить, но я попробовал и сработало, обновились что-ли так? спасибо большое!

Comment: andreymal следы преступления стерты))

Comment: И `-a` тут лишнее

Answer (score 0):

На вашем месте я бы делал так:

1. Вносим изменения в файлы
2. `git diff` - смотрим что поменяли
3. `git add /нужный файл` - Добавляем файл
4. `git commit` -  Откроется редактор, комитим изменения
5. Повторяем процедуру с 2 по 4 пункт для остальных файлов
6. `git push туда куда нужно` - Отправляем изменения в удаленных репо
   **А если вы что то релизете то добавляйте теги.**

А если вы хотите добавить и закомитить все файлы одной командой делайте это так ⠀⠀`git commit -am "my commit"`